# Changing plymouth boot splash

Tags: raspbian, pixel

Is it possible to change to "Raspbian with PIXEL" boot splash to some other image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Simon Long's (creator of PIXEL) comment [here on the Rasperry Pi blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/#comment-1263848):

> The splash screen is a PNG file at
>   /usr/share/plymouth/themes/pix/splash.png – you can change the image
>   to whatever you want as long as you use the same file name.

Comment: Is there a way to change the pixel theme to the fade in theme?

Comment: We found out that this works fine for the Raspberry Pi 3, but the Zero has some problems. It is not deterministic but sometimes the splash screen on the zero shows just three dots and sometimes it is skipped completely. We were not able to solve this so far.